# How to create cluster values?

Tags: haskell, graphviz

I'm trying to draw graphs with nested clusters using the [GraphViz package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz-2999.17.0.1/docs/Data-GraphViz.html), but I'm having trouble understanding how to use the constructors of the [`NodeCluster`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz-2999.17.0.1/docs/Data-GraphViz.html#t:NodeCluster) type:

```
N a 
C c (NodeCluster c a)
```

The picture I have in mind is that the clusters are arranged in a tree (representing the nesting) and labelled by labels cl, but I don't see how it translates to the above.

Specifically, I'm writing the following function. The two comments describe what I'm trying to do.

```
makeClusterParams :: (Show el) => (Node -> nl -> String) -> (Node -> nl -> (cl,Maybe cl)) -> Gr nl el -> GraphvizParams Node nl el cl nl
makeClusterParams f g graph = nonClusteredParams {
  clusterBy = cb,
  fmtNode = fn,
  fmtEdge = fe
  }
  where
    cb (xn,xl) = 
      case g xn xl of 
        (thisCluster, Just parentCluster) -> --put this node inside of thisCluster, and put thisCluster inside of parentCluster
        (thisCluster, Nothing) -> --put this node in the top-level cluster.
    fn (xn,xl) = [(Label . StrLabel. pack) (f xn xl)]
    fe (xm,xn,l) = [(Label . StrLabel. pack) (show l)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This type doesn't represent a tree. Instead, it seems to represent a path, from the root to the specific node.

It seems that your approach is fundamentally wrong. What if `g xn1 xl1` returns `(thisCluster, Just parentCluster1)`, and `g xn2 xl2` returns `(thisCluster, Just parentCluster2)`? Do you expect `thisCluster` to be put into two different parents?